# Rxswift Update Tableview cell value

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am able to bind an Observable sequence of data to a table. 
Now lets say i have a button on each cell which on click changes the 
label of that cell to new value. How to do this ?

I have done so far as follows

I have created an `@IBAction` for that button in the cell pointing class

then i am doing

```
label.text = "new text"
```

but when i scroll down then scroll up, the label show previous value not the new value

previously when i use array and set each value to a cell i used to update that array item and called `tableview.reloadData`.

how can i do this in RxSwift??

I have done so far

```
tableview.dataSource = nil (then)
myData.bindTo ... (bind again)
```

This does not seem to me the right way. so what is the appropriate way to deal with this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to achive this with RxSwiftCommunity Action

`https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/Action`

ViewController

```
variable.asObservable().bindTo(mytable.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cell")) { (row, person, cell) in
            if let cellToUse = cell as? TableViewCell {
                cellToUse.person = Variable(person)
                cellToUse.button1.rx.action = cellToUse.action
            }
            }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

and in cell

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let action = CocoaAction { input in
        return .just(input)
    }

    var person : Variable<Person>!{
        didSet {
            self.updateUI()
        }
    }

    private func updateUI(){
        person.asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                person in
                let name : Observable<String> = Observable.of(person.name)
                let age : Observable<String> = Observable.of("\(person.age)")
                _ = name.bindTo(self.label1.rx.text)
                _ = age.bindTo(self.label2.rx.text)
            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        action.elements
            .asObservable()
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                _ in
                self.label2.text = "asd"

            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

like before not sure if this is the right way but it worked for me

thanks to (`https://rxswift.slack.com/messages/@fpillet`) for showing me the way

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `self.updateUI()` every time you set `person`. It creates a new binding every time you call it. You should setup this binding once. Or just use update the name and age directly in didSet and not use any binding at all.